# How to disable compaction in cassandra and kick start again at end?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am inserting records in billions into cassandra simultaneously. So, to utilize resource I need to disable the compaction at the time the insertion is in progress. Once the insertion is done I should be able to manually kick start the Compaction. I am using hector-core-1.0-5 as API to connect to cassandra. Can any one help me in how to do this.

Comment: have you considered sstableloader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the compaction for a column family via the management console (JMX). You can disable before loading and then force major compaction after data loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The method I used was to use the cassandra-cli to update the column family compression options.

to turn on

```
use myks;
update column family mycf with compression_options={sstable_compression:SnappyCompressor, chunk_length_kb:64};
```

and then off:

```
use myks;
update column family mycf with compression_options=null;
```

You will have to force a rebuild of sstables after this update using nodetool (scrub) if you want the update immediately, else might happen when unexpected.

I only did this in testing, to compare sizes of compressed vs non-compressed column families. But I found it better to enable compression and then do the bulk loads, otherwise the sstable rebuild took forever.

Comment: @libjack.. I want to know about the Compaction.. You are answer is relevant to Compression.. Same time I cannot not use node tool or cli as I am using cassandra integrated with java..